# Cannot install Tensorflow object_detection in Google Colab

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory

I've been trying to bring my code which uses the [Tensorflow object detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) into Google Colab (Python 3, T4 GPU), but I cannot seem to install the object detection API. I've looked at a few tutorials that installed it, but they seem to be outdated. Here is a minimal example to reproduce the following error:

```py
!pip install pip --upgrade
%cd /content
!git clone --quiet https://github.com/tensorflow/models.git

%cd /content/models/research/
!protoc object_detection/protos/*.proto --python_out=.
%cp object_detection/packages/tf2/setup.py .
!python -m pip install .
```

When I run this I get the following error:

```
/content/models/research
Processing /content/models/research
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting avro-python3 (from object-detection==0.1)
  Using cached avro-python3-1.10.2.tar.gz (38 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting apache-beam (from object-detection==0.1)
  Obtaining dependency information for apache-beam from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/7c/43adabfa0e14014419cd9baa52e8923f524d52349239bebde6e0f3d89248/apache_beam-2.50.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Using cached apache_beam-2.50.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (6.0 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: pillow in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (9.4.0)
Requirement already satisfied: lxml in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (4.9.3)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (3.7.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Cython in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (3.0.2)
Requirement already satisfied: contextlib2 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (21.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tf-slim in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: six in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycocotools in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (2.0.7)
Collecting lvis (from object-detection==0.1)
  Using cached lvis-0.5.3-py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (1.11.2)
Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (1.5.3)
Collecting tf-models-official>=2.5.1 (from object-detection==0.1)
  Obtaining dependency information for tf-models-official>=2.5.1 from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c9/c6/881f37a807affc009ccf84dfd9964b622e91e664f23a1cec1e443aa66ed1/tf_models_official-2.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached tf_models_official-2.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Collecting tensorflow_io (from object-detection==0.1)
  Obtaining dependency information for tensorflow_io from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/74/e6/e1b9e62dad8eeb509c842d76363ed4a34cd17e2b751610cc993e57b14f2c/tensorflow_io-0.34.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl.metadata
  Using cached tensorflow_io-0.34.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_12_x86_64.manylinux2010_x86_64.whl.metadata (14 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: keras in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from object-detection==0.1) (2.13.1)
Collecting pyparsing==2.4.7 (from object-detection==0.1)
  Using cached pyparsing-2.4.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl (67 kB)
Collecting sacrebleu<=2.2.0 (from object-detection==0.1)
  Using cached sacrebleu-2.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (116 kB)
Collecting portalocker (from sacrebleu<=2.2.0->object-detection==0.1)
  Using cached portalocker-2.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: regex in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from sacrebleu<=2.2.0->object-detection==0.1) (2023.6.3)
Requirement already satisfied: tabulate>=0.8.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from sacrebleu<=2.2.0->object-detection==0.1) (0.9.0)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.17 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from sacrebleu<=2.2.0->object-detection==0.1) (1.23.5)
Collecting colorama (from sacrebleu<=2.2.0->object-detection==0.1)
  Using cached colorama-0.4.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: gin-config in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (0.5.0)
Requirement already satisfied: google-api-python-client>=1.6.7 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (2.84.0)
Collecting immutabledict (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1)
  Obtaining dependency information for immutabledict from https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/df/ef/e038d0d7cd1954c46402a0c27794dd93982c40632085046efb6ab8aa6c1d/immutabledict-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata
  Using cached immutabledict-3.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: kaggle>=1.3.9 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (1.5.16)
Requirement already satisfied: oauth2client in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (4.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: opencv-python-headless in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (4.8.0.76)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil>=5.4.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (5.9.5)
Requirement already satisfied: py-cpuinfo>=3.3.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1) (9.0.0)
Collecting pyyaml<5.4.0,>=5.1 (from tf-models-official>=2.5.1->object-detection==0.1)
  Using cached PyYAML-5.3.1.tar.gz (269 kB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I've tried to change the version of pyyaml, but I get a similar error:

```py
!pip install pyyaml==5.4.0
```

error:

```
Collecting pyyaml==5.4.0
  Using cached PyYAML-5.4.tar.gz (268 kB)
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> See above for output.
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

I've also tried to update `wheel` and `setuptools`.

Edit: There was a dependency conflict which was recently [fixed](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/commit/623a471131e905436c3b21205075b031e1bc4795), preventing these errors and allowing for installation.

Comment: Yeah, I had same issue.
Please let me know if you have any ideas to resolve this. Thank you so much

Comment: I reproduced your code and it works fine `Successfully installed object-detection-0.1`

Comment: @MiftakhulArzak Likewise! There was a commit on 9/11/2023 which fixed the dependency version (https://github.com/tensorflow/models/commit/623a471131e905436c3b21205075b031e1bc4795)